# What's the best way to redirect a user to a page only if certain conditions are valid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using React for my SPA. I know how `Routes` work, and I know how to make a `PrivateRoute`.

The problem is that I need to verify my users identity before they being able to use a `PrivateRoute`. I tried to implement it like this:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                if (isAuthenticated()) {
                    if (isVerified()) {
                        return <Component {...props} />;
                    } else if (isInProcess()) {
                        // replace url and render verification component
                        history.push("/inverification");
                    } else {
                        // replace url and render document upload
                        history.push("/documentupload");
                        return <DocumentUpload />;
                    }
                } else {
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/login",
                                state: { from: props.location }
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }
            }}
        />
    );
}

export default function Routes() {
    // manage mobile drawer
    const [drawer, setDrawer] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="root-div">
                    <Navbar setDrawer={setDrawer} />
                    <Drawer drawer={drawer} setDrawer={setDrawer} />
                    <div className="content-div">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                            <Route
                                path="/login/callback"
                                component={Callback}
                            />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                            <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                            <PrivateRoute
                                path="/test"
                                component={() => <h1>Success</h1>}
                            />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

So when logging in, I save a cookie with some information about my user, encoded in a `JWT` token.

`isVerified()` and `isInProcess()` check if the user is already able to use the `PrivateRoute`. If `isVerified()` is `true`, then he can proceed to the component, else it checks if the user is in the process of being verified.

What I need to do is:

1. Right after the user signup, the form saves the user info and push the history to `/documentupload`. I need this component to render ONLY if `isVerified()` and `isInProcess()` are false.
2. If the user already submitted his documents and `isInProcess()` is true, than I need to push to `/inverification` and render another component, but ONLY if `isInProcess()` is true and `isVerified()` is false.
3. For both the above cases, `isAuthenticated()` must be true.

The way I implemented don't work, it renders a blank page instead of rendering the `<DocumentUpload />` component.

My question is: what's the best way to achieve what I need?

I think that creating another function, like `function DocumentUploadVerification` similar to the `PrivateRoute` function is a way, but I guess it will be too verbose, and there might be a better way to solve it.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your component never rerenders again. in this case you can repeat isInProcess|isVerified checks or use state manager like redux for storing current state for isInProcess|isVerified

```js
const [_isInProcess, setIsInProcess] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const i = setInterval(() => {
    if (isInProcess()) {
      setIsInProcess(true);
      clearInterval(i);
    }
 }, 200);

 clearInterval(i);
}, []);
```

Comment: The problem is not with the checks, but how to render the page using react-router. My checks are working fine, I don't need a state for them. Thanks for your answer btw

Comment: Your page is not reacting to JWT changes

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
history.push("/documentupload");
return <DocumentUpload />;
```

you will be switched to the /documentupload route that doesn't exist in your Routes component and that is the reason you are seeing the blank page. What I would do is:

In routes add a new entry:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/documentupload" component={DocumentUpload} />
```

and remove return  from PrivateRoute. This way DocumentUpload will be "protected" + history.push will save you from a recursion problem since when you try to push the location you are already on it will just ignore it(if you don't like the warning you can always add a check if you are already in that location).

Hope this helps.